# Is there a way to highlight a background using jQuery Bootstrap Slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap-slider

I'm trying to highlight the background of the slider using the low track (left background of slider) and right track (right side of slider) using bootstrap-slider.

I would like my slider to only reveal a yellow background when the slider moves to the left or right. Similar to how this slider example reveals a black background:
https://jsfiddle.net/leongersen/9hyfv0bw/11/

So far the code below is what I have:

https://jsfiddle.net/jimmyt1001/96zj2wnf/9/

```
  #slider12a .slider-track-high, #slider12c .slider-track-high {
      background: green;
    }


    #slider12c .slider-selection {
      background: yellow;
    }

<input id="ex12c" type="text"/><br/>

$("#ex12c").slider({ 
 id: "slider12c", 
 min: 0, 
 max: 40, 
 range: false,
 value: 20 });
```

Comment: Looks like you need to add another div underneath the slider and have it mimic the width left and right when selected

Comment: @Keith Sounds doable. Do you have an example?

Comment: If you look at your example, it first creates an element: let node = document.createElement('div'); , then it adds the class to it ( not sure why it doesn't just do it all in one line but whatever ) : node.classList.add('fake-fill'); , then on the slider usage ( I would think it would be a "change" element for you ), it does an if/else statement on where the slider is positioned based on where it starts and it adds the width there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's do more or less like the example you posted.

You can create a div (let's call its class `middleTrack`) with two elements (`.left` and `.right`) absolutely positioned inside it that will have the yellow background.

Then, position them and create a function called using the method `.on(slide, middleTrackFunction)` that will apply a calculated width relative to the tracker situation. Run it once to apply from the beginning. Also, hide `.slider-selection` element somehow to prevent it from invading the new trackers.

**jQuery:**

```
$("#ex12c").slider({
    id: "slider12c",
    min: 0,
    max: 40,
    range: false,
    alue: 20
}).on('slide', middleTrackFunction);

$(".slider-track").prepend("<div class='middleTrack'><div class='left'></div><div class='right'></div>");

function middleTrackFunction() { // call whenever slide happens
    var halfWidth = $('.middleTrack').width() / 2;
    var leftWidth = $('.slider-selection').width();
    var rightWidth = $('.slider-track-high').width();
    $('.middleTrack .right').width(leftWidth - halfWidth);
    $('.middleTrack .left').width(rightWidth - halfWidth);
}

middleTrackFunction(); // run at least once
```

**CSS:**

```
#slider12a .slider-track-high, #slider12c .slider-track-high {
    background: transparent;
}
.middleTrack div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    background: yellow;
}
.middleTrack .left {
    right: 50%;
}
.middleTrack .right {
    left: 50%;
}
.slider-selection {
    z-index: -1;
}
```